# ¿Como agregar una letra a un grupo de números?

Tags: python

Hola amigos de Stack Over Flow, tengo el siguiente problema, por ejemplo al número guardado en la variable s (2.45), necesito agregarle o bien las letras B o C de tal forma que me quede asi B2.45 o C2.45, a continuación les muestro un programa que escribí pero no tengo ese resultado.

```
s = 2.45

lista_s = list(s)

lista = [1,2]

comando = int(input('ingresar números 1 o 2'))

if comando == 1 in lista:

    print(s.append('B'))

if comando == 2 in lista:

    print(s.append('C'))
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En python las cadenas son inmutables. No puedes añadirles cosas con `.append()` (y en todo caso `.append()` añadiría al final y no delante).

Lo que sí puedes hacer es utilizar cualquiera de las funciones de formateo de cadenas para crear cadenas nuevas, a base de "juntar" información en otras variables, en tu caso la variable `s`:

```
resultado = "B{}".format(s)
```

Si usas Python 3.6 o superior:

```
resultado = f"B{s}"
```

Incluso una concatenación habría servido:

```
resultado = "B" + str(s)
```

### Nota

Tu código tiene más errores, por los que no has preguntado. Por ejemplo ¿qué se supone que quieres hacer con `if comando == 1 in lista`? Supongo que basta con `if comando == 1`. Además tienes alguna comilla sin cerrar, y algún paréntesis.

Comment: ¿Con listas inmutables querías decir cadenas? Porque me has dejado descolocado :)

Comment: @AdriánSanzWallace Huy, sí! Gracias por verlo. Corregido

Comment: Menos mal, porque habiéndolo puesto tú, ya me había hecho dudar! Jejeje

Answer (score 2):

Te complicas mucho la vida. Es más sencillo:

```
s = 2.45

comando = input('ingresar números 1 o 2')

if comando == "1":
    print(f"B{s}")
elif comando == "2":
    print(f"C{s}")
```

No necesito realmente convertir la entrada a entero; basta con compararla contra el caracter correspondiente.

Para anteponer el caracter deseado, use el formato de edición f-strings. Con esta forma puedo insertar expresiones Python encerrandolas entre "{}", como `{s}` en este caso. La expresión es evaluada y el resultado usado para formar la cadena final.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por sus respuestas

Answer (score 2):

Aunque ya te han dicho dos buenas soluciones, pongo otra más:

```
s = 2.45

comando = int(input('ingresar números 1 o 2'))
d = {1: f'B{s}', 2: f'C{s}'}
print(d[comando])
```